# Holder returning wrong values

Tags: android, adapter, android-viewholder

In my getView method when I am trying click an imagebutton of a view,Imagebutton of its adjacent view is being clicked and same for the other UI's,which means it is returning wrong view each time.I am not able to figure out where the problem is.

> Adapter Class

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView iv;
    //View v = convertView;
    String content = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(convertView==null) {
        convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item2,parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();  
        pos=position;



        holder.read_more=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.readMore);
        holder.share=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.share);
        holder.heading = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.heading);
        holder.date = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        holder.message = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.message);
        holder.gridview=(GridView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        holder.comment_executed=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.comments);
        holder.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        holder.like_img=(ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.like);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }else {
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.read_more.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.gridview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.heading.setText(Html.fromHtml(modelList.get(position).getTitle()));
    //String setDate=parseDate(modelList.get(position).getDate());
    holder.date.setText(modelList.get(position).getDate());
    holder.like_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context,holder.heading.getText()+" "+modelList.get(position).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            holder.like_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_arrow_hover);
        }
    });
    holder.gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                        int position, long id) {

                    // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, FullImageActivity.class);
                    // passing array index
                    i.putExtra("id", position);
                   context.startActivity(i);
                }
            });
    content=Html.fromHtml(modelList.get(position).getContent())+"";
    size=content.length();

                    String altered_string="";
        if(size>200) {
            altered_string=content.substring(0,200);
            holder.message.setText(altered_string+"...");
            holder.read_more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.read_more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    intent_to_details=new Intent(v.getContext(),PostDetail.class);
                    Log.e("after",position+"");
                    intent_to_details.putExtra("list", modelList.get(position));
                    ((Activity)context).startActivity(intent_to_details);

                }
            });
        }else {
        holder.message.setText(Html.fromHtml(modelList.get(position).getContent()));
        }
        holder.message.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        holder.message.setLinksClickable(true);

        if(modelList.get(position).getModelChild().size() != 0) {
            if(modelList.get(position).getModelChild().size() ==1) {
                Bitmap bit;
                child_list=modelList.get(position).getModelChild();
                flag=true;
                holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(child_list.get(0).getImage_normal(),loader,holder.image);
                //new DoAsync().execute(child_list);

            }else {
            holder.gridview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            child_list=modelList.get(position).getModelChild();
            new DoAsync().execute(modelList.get(position).getModelChild());
            }
        }
        holder.comment_executed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, ((Activity)context).MODE_PRIVATE );
            if(prefs.getString("succ", "").equals("success") || (Session.getActiveSession() != null)) {
                Toast.makeText(context,holder.heading.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                int post_id=Integer.parseInt(modelList.get(position).getId());
                intent_to_commentClass=new Intent(context,Comments.class);
                Log.e("post id sent: ","position:  "+position+"  post id:   "+post_id+"");
                intent_to_commentClass.putExtra("post_id", post_id);
                context.startActivity(intent_to_commentClass);

            }else {
                intent_to_login=new Intent(context,LoginClass.class);
                context.startActivity(intent_to_login);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please login first to like or comment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }
        }); 




    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: on which click you are facing problem?

Comment: holder.like_img (its an ImageButton)

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify after performing any changes.

```
holder.like_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context,holder.heading.getText()+" "+modelList.get(position).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            holder.like_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.up_arrow_hover);
            notifyDataSetChanged();//notify after any changes
        }
    });
```

Comment: it is performing click action on the next infalted view's imagebutton but not on current view.

Comment: That means issue in your position variable.
Please debug to check the position